# post multiple links inside textbox to another page and insert into mysql separately

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html form in php file in which there is a textbox in which a user can post multiple links . suppose

```
www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm
www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm
www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm
www.4shared.com/video/UryixZ7l/Puppy_loves_ringtones.htm
```

There are four links here . If i submit the form and the data is send to target page then it counts the whole textbox suppose named "links" as a string and send all of its data into database which it should . But i wanted to send these links and the data along with them such as uid , name to be submitted 4 times into database ie as many times as many links are there instead on 1 entry with all four links and the name and id in one row . How can i make this possible ?

Comment: you could use preg_match to match all the extensions that you allow, then explode the results after that extension and store them in an array?

Comment: or actually, why not comma or line separate each link within the textbox, then you would just need to explode on that comma and store in your separate variables

Comment: will the links always end in '.htm'? are the links generated by you or taken from elsewhere?

Comment: @a7omiton thank you for your reply . Its not about matching extentions at the moment . Its like how to break these into four parts or how to tell php to do that and submit four or as many links there are times the values into database

Comment: check it out: http://uk1.php.net/explode

Comment: thank you for the link but ill explode after what ? there is no comma or anything like that that can help me identify that a new link is going to start ?

Comment: yeah somehow you would need to tell that the end of a link is reached and insert a delimiter using javascript,  or instruct the user at minimum to separate each link on a new line...am thinking about how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I edited this entire post after I got more information by the author*

Assuming you are using a textarea where the user can enter his information you could process that in PHP:

```
<form action="mytarget.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="urls"></textarea>
</form>
```

Assuming the user should enter one URL per line, on PHP:

```
$data = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);
if(count($data) > 0) {
    foreach($data as $url) {
        echo $url . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Maybe this are the droids you are looking for. :P

Comment: I am using form :( THe very traditional one no jquery

Comment: and i am taking the values as 4 link as an example it can be as many as a user would input

Comment: Ah I see its a user input, well, what kind of input do you got there, is this a textarea?

Comment: but he would somehow have to enforce that the user will put each link on a new line. wondering how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I've been trying to figure how a technique with just the textarea:
This does use jQuery, I'm not sure if that is something you want to do or not. You can easily convert it to javascript if you like.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('textarea').on('focusout', function() {
            var text = $('textarea').val();

            var delimiter = ",";

            $('textarea').val(text + delimiter);

        });

    });
</script>
```

What that does is appends a comma to the end of each url when the user focuses out of the textarea (pick whichever event you want, i don't expect you to use focusout), so that when your form is submitted, you can then explode the textareas text and get the urls and store them in separate variables.

The regular expression will expect the url to always end in .htm, so if you are wanting other url endings then add to the regex.

This will add a delimiter after every focusout event, even if its just plain text (i.e. not a valid url). But you can check against this once you've exploded (the text I mean :D), and it can be a good way to sanitize your data to make sure you're getting valid urls.

Hope this helps in some way

PS, the delimiter can be anything, i.e. a new line would be best `\n`, just remember to use the same delimiter in `explode()` i.e. `explode("\n", $_POST[urls]);`